# PHPMailer - adding attachment breaks charset

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've got a simple e-mail being sent from my script using PHPMailer:

```
 include_once("class.phpmailer.php");
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->IsMail();
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
 $mail->AddAddress($email); 
 $mail->Subject  = $subject;
 $mail->Body = $content;
```

the above is sent perfectly, even if both subject and body contain foreign characters.

However if I add an attachment:

```
$mail->AddAddress($email); 
$mail->AddAttachment("file.pdf");
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
```

the characters are replaced by `ÅÄ`

I've been using PHP Mailer for years but it's the first time I have to use both attachments and foreign characters in the message. Strangely the subject is fine, just the body of the e-mail is broken.

Has anybody experienced same/similar problem?

Comment: I'll look into this more later, but first up, make sure you're using latest PHPMailer from GitHub.